# Moving a Google Cloud Platform project from one account to another account

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine

Can I migrate a project from one GCP account to another account? Account 1 has project 1 and Account 2 has Project 2. Account 1 and Account 2 have different sized Compute Engines. Would like to add Project 1 to Account 2 to get the benefit of a unified Compute Engine.

Thanks
-ravi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "Account" you mean "Billing Account", yes you can move projects between billing accounts. Instructions are at https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6293499?hl=en.

If you "Account" you mean between different Google Accounts, you can also do that. Just add the new account as a project owner.

Answer (score 1):

Migrating projects with no organization

To migrate a project, you will need the Project Creator role (roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator) on the organization to which you want to migrate your project. You will also need the Project Mover role (roles/resourcemanager.projectMover) on the project you are migrating. If you don't have these roles, the target organization won't appear in the Google Cloud Platform Console as a choice for migration.

Project migration isn't reversible. After a project is associated with an organization, you can't change it back to No organization or move it to another organization on your own. If you want to move a project after it's associated with an organization, contact GCP Support.

To migrate a project into an organization:

1. To migrate a project into an organization:
2. On the Select organization drop-down list at the top of the page, select No Organization, and then select the project you want to migrate.
3. At the top of the page, click Migrate.
4. On the Organization drop-down list, select the organization you want to migrate your project to.
5. After a project is added to an organization, you cannot undo the selection on your own.

Link: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing#migrating_projects_with_no_organization