# Is there a way to change a google cloud platform project to other GCP account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is there away how can i change google cloud platform to other GCP account ? Because my account has suspended via my company. Thank you

Comment: If account suspended by company then contact your company.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897093/moving-a-google-cloud-platform-project-from-one-account-to-another-account

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving a Google Cloud Platform project from one account to another account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897093/moving-a-google-cloud-platform-project-from-one-account-to-another-account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change a project owner, billing account or other options.

To change the organization of a project, you have to directly contact google as stated here: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing#migrating_projects_in_an_organization

Answer (score 0):

If your project is part of an organization, you can only move the project within the organization. You cannot move the project outside the organization even if you change the owner. The `owner` is just a permission, not who controls the hierachy of organizations / folders / projects.

If the project is not part of an organization, you can change the owner to any Google Accounts email address. Just remember to delete the other owners. You will need ownership of the billing account also.