# Google Firebase add app, problem with SHA

Tags: android, firebase

I face a problem when I'm trying to add the app to google firebase
[the firebase error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vsa7T.png)[image]

I'm trying to move project from other account. In [the documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6401008?authuser=0) mention that I should import it, but I don't have this option.

Do any body have idea how to do it?

Comment: android studio was mention in the TAG cause I use this IDE one of the solution can be change the fingerprint for app. @marcin-orlowski

Comment: can you put screen shot in english language ? It would be more useful.

Comment: it doesn't look so easy I don't see language flag in the address :(

Comment: or you can send me the translation of this error because i am not able to understand what screenshot shows.

Comment: it's easy google says that "OAuth2.0 key and app name used in another app in the Firebse or Google Cloud" but i just delete the app and project from another google firebase account.

Comment: Google will take 4-5 days to delete your project from firebase so wait for it and try again.

Comment: it can take longer during 30 days app would be suspended, but easy way just change owner https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897093/moving-a-google-cloud-platform-project-from-one-account-to-another-account, you shold do it in cloud console https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project